# Position of nodes in TikZ matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I would like to be able to put a comment below an element in the last row of a TikZ matrix. I thought that the MWE below would allow me to do that, but it does not. To be specific, I thought the MWE below would print "hello" below element 9.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix
  {
    \node {8}; &[2mm] \node{1}; &[-1mm] \node {6}; \\
    \node {3}; &      \node{5}; &       \node {7}; \\
    \node {4}; &      \node(a){9}; &    \node {2}; \\
  };
  \node (a.south) {hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `\node [below] at (a.south) {hello}` works.  Without the `at` you are defining a new node named `(a.south)`.

[image]

### Why no error message?

- Leaving out the `at` does not generate an error as it is perfectly valid syntax.  So,

  ```
   \node (X) {text 1};
  ```

  defines a coordinate named `(X)`  at the current location, and

  ```
   \node at (Y) {text 2};
  ```

  places the given text `at` the coordinate named `(Y)`.

  In your specific example, the first use of `\node (a) {9}` was defining a coordinate named `(a)` at the point where the `node` containing the text `9` is located.  Your second use (where you were trying to place `hello`) was defining a coordinate named `(a.south)` without explicitly specifying *where* you wanted this `node` placed.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix
  {
    \node {8}; &[2mm] \node{1}; &[-1mm] \node {6}; \\
    \node {3}; &      \node{5}; &       \node {7}; \\
    \node {4}; &      \node(a){9}; &    \node {2}; \\
  };
  \node  [below] at (a.south) {hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why is the "at" necessary - or put another way - why does a missing "at" not lead to an error?

Comment: @user1362373: Have updated answer. Please let me know if that clarifies things.